# Reduced if/else block

Tags: python

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable according to some input. This is what I currently do:

```
if a == 1:
    var = 'some_value'
elif a == 2:
    var = 'another_one'
elif a == 3:
    var = 'text_string'
elif a == 4:
    var = 'one_more'
elif a == 5:
    var = 'final_str'
```

So basically it maps a given value to `var` according to the value of `a`. Could this be *pythonified* somehow?

Comment: is `value_1` the actual value you want to assign, or a place holder?

Comment: Will `var` always depend so directly on `a`? Martijn's answer solves this specific case, but in the general case a dictionary `{a: var}` is the best solution.

Comment: @Hoopdady it is the actual value but the text string don't always look like `value_x`. I've amended that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ugh, that's what I get for typing fast. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
var_map = {1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 10: 'spam'}
var = var_map[a]
```

If `a` is a sequential integer, you can use a list too:

```
var_map = [None, 'some_value', 'another_one', 'text_string', 'one_more', 'final_str']
var = var_map[a]
```

Here `var_map[0]` is set to `None` to keep the sequence map simple.

Comment: Also, single = for the assignments.

Comment: This looks great but the string used is not necessarily always `value_x` , I just used that as an example. Sorry, I'll make it more clear in the question now.

Comment: @Gabriel: your example was way too simple then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I apologize.

Comment: I won't write an answer because Martijn will change his answer faster than anyone else could answer this.

Comment: Lol, that's not even fair. Changing your answer after you've already got 5 upvotes. :P

Comment: The new answer is worth all those upvotes either way.

Comment: @Hoopdady: well, the question changed. It was change with it or be obsolete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah Yeah Yeah

Comment: And that's why Martijn is #1 per the ad on the side ----> (wait for it...)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a dictionary if you're going to run this if block multiple times.

```
d = {
      '1':'value_1',
      '2':'value_2',
      '3':'value_3',
      '4':'value_4',
      '5':'value_5'
    }

var = d[a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `list` or (IMHO better) a `dict`:

```
VALUES = {1: "a", 2:"b", 3:"c", } # etc
var = VALUES.get(a, "some default value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have essentially key / value pairs, if you have them in some sort of iterable in the corresponding order, you could marry them this way:

```
dictionary_for_a = {}
for x,y in zip(a,var):
    dictionary_for_a[x] = y
```

Comment: Is "zip" less pythonic? Just wondering about the "why" of the downvote.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, so I'm only guessing, but it seems to me your answer doesn't answer the question that was asked.  Your answer would be more responsive to the question "what's the best way to construct the dictionary, since I've already decided that I want to use one?"

Comment: In the OP's code, `a` is an integer, and you can't zip an int with anything. And `var` doesn't exist until after the big if/elif block executes, so you can't replace that big block with this code.

Comment: Ah, so it's unclear that I mean OP should have the "a" values that are options in an iterable?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a `switch` Statements.

This is my method:

```
# All conditions make a dict
condition = {1:'some_value',
             2:'another_one',
             3:'text_string',
             4:'one_more',
             5:'final_str'}

i = 4
if i in condition.keys():
    var = condition[i]

print var # 'one_more'
```